# AddToRoleAsync() freezes IIS(?) on Chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-express

If I run this in Chrome, it stalls, Firefox runs smoothly...

I have the following controller:

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

public StartUpsController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}


public async Task<IActionResult> GetLogin(InputModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("O usuário criou uma nova conta com senha.");

                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Startup");

                return RedirectToAction("StartupBasicData");
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

If I run in debugging mode, line per line, everything works, if I run in debugging ([F5]) without a breakpoint, and thus running all the code at once, it runs perfectly as well... But if I run normally ([CTRL][F5]) it freezes, no error messages, no nothing... It just hangs there.

If I comment out the line

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Startup");
```

it works!

Any idea how to run it outside the debugging mode?

Comment: Run it until it freezes and *then* attach the debugger and see where it froze (what line of code is executing).

Comment: Do you see any log output? Perhaps you could add in a lot more logging to see where it gets to in this method.

Comment: @igor Sorry I know how either run in debug or out of it... How to attach the debugger after it freezes I don't have any idea on how to do it...

Comment: @igor If I comment out the line

     await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Startup");

it works

Comment: What is `_userManager` and what is the implementation of `AddToRoleAsync`? Is that your code?

Comment: @igor _userManager is the implementation of the Identity native to Core, that is:

    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

And AddToRoleAsync is one of its primitives... In other words, all native to ASP.NeT Core Identity

Comment: Do you have any other code that you are running that is not shown in your question where you use `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter()` with a `Task` or `Task<T>` ? That could create a deadlock.

Comment: @igor This class is a controller, so yes, there are more "public async Task<IActionResult>", but no .Result nor GetAwaiter().

And again it was ok for more than a month before I inserted the line "public async Task<IActionResult>"... And works fine if's not there... Remembering the fun is that in debugging mode is all right

Comment: @igor Nope... Still the same...

Comment: What is your .net core version? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Your code works under .net core 2.2. Not sure whether it will work, but you could try `var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); var dbUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);  if (result.Succeeded)  { await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(dbUser, "Startup"); return Ok("StartupBasicData");  }`

Comment: Have the same thing in ASP.Net. Trying to add a role to the user, "Administrator", and it just hangs with a LOT of Garbage Collection events in the diagnostic tools graph. The `await this.AddToRoleAsync(userId, role);` is asp.net code and not my own, cant step into it to see what's happening

Comment: Turns out it was an infinite loop.